# What's the best way to have a gigantic ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I need an ArrayList in Java that can have up to a million entries (I don't make the rules, I just implement them). ArrayList will clearly die well before 1 million (it may get there, but it's going to take a looong time). LinkedList won't work because there are places where I need to access it with get(index).

What's the best approach for this? The best I've thought of is a 2-step array where the main array's elements point to a subset of the array. So each array holds 1,000 objects and the main array can point to 1,000 of these sub-arrays.

The array is not sparse and is built up in order. And mostly then accessed in order.

Update for some of the questions below:

1. I do need ArrayList (or an equivalent) for the functionality I need.
2. I do need it all in memory at once.
3. I don't know how large it will be in advance. Normally it will be 4 - 20 elements. But at rare times it can be a million.
4. I'm finding that once the array gets over 120K entries, it pauses about every 30 or so adds to it. So I'm assuming growing an ArrayList takes time as it gets large.

**Update 2:**

With some of the responses to this saying ArrayList should be fast enough, I wrote a small test routine to create a million row array one add() at a time. And it is (gotta dig into my code to see why that looks like the problem as it isn't).

LinkedList seconds = 0.136

ArrayList seconds = 0.087

Comment: Use an embedded database or an external cache.

Comment: "Best" depends on your requirements.  Will you have memory enough?  Will you have diskspace enough?  Will the entries be easily recalculatable if you need to discard some of them due to memory constraints?  Will you need the whole array at once or is it enough with an interator?

Comment: take a look on this http://acs.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/

Comment: Why will `ArrayList` clearly die?  If you have the heap space, you can easily call [`new ArrayList<>(DESIRED_SIZE);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) and get your array.

Comment: By "array" do you mean "List" or even "list-like structure?" An array in Java is a specific thing, and there is only one way in Java to create an array that can hold a million entries: `new Whatever[1000000]`. If that's not what you mean, you need to be more specific about what you do mean.

Comment: I added an update to answer the questions in these comments.

Answer (score 3):

Given an array A, the index is of type `integer`, meaning it can have several million entries.  Therefore the simplest way to have an array with a million entries of type O in it is to use

```
O[] o = new O[1000000];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how many entries in advance. I need to add them as I get them. It could be 1. It's normally 4 - 20. But it could also be 1,000,000.

Comment: Then your title is inaccurate.  You need a list.

Comment: I didn't want to limit solutions but I changed it because that did seem to be making it unclear for some. The biggie is I don't know the size in advance, otherwise a plain old array would be perfect.

Comment: Note that you could make a new bigger array when outgrowing this (and keep track of the last index manually) and copy the content. Efficient methods exist for the copying. In other words do explicitly what the array list does.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're doing is adding elements, accessing elements by index and sequentially iterating through elements, why would ArrayList have problems? ArrayList is very efficient at all of those operations.

If you're really talking about having an array that is much larger than you can support, heapwise, what you're really talking about is database access. If you think about your array as being a database table with the index of each element being represented in an integer column, this is very easy to implement.

If you don't care about latency, you can just create an index for that column in your database and do selects by the indexed column, which is reasonably efficient (though not as fast as accessing a reference in memory, obviously). If you care about latency and can predict beforehand which elements you will probably be accessing, some sort of caching mechanism can easily be made to fit your memory and object access requirements.

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea what your latency requirements are and your question doesn't really specify how you will be using this giant array, so this vague asspull is the best I can do.

Comment: Yes it does all need to be in memory. And I'm finding that ArrayList, as it grows over 120K, takes time about every 30th or so add. So O think there is a hit as it gets big enough for resizing.

Comment: This might be something else, like a garbage collection.  The arraylist resizes exponentially and not linearly

Comment: Maybe preallocate the array? It's creating a new array and copying the references every time you exceed the current capacity. Even so, this is an efficient operation. Also, java increases the array by a percentage of its current size (don't remember how much, but it's a big percentage), and in any case, there are only log(n) reallocations for an array of n size, regardless of the percentage increase in size for each reallocation.